Optical properties calculation with Quantum ESPRESSO
I am using the following code for measuring quantum espresso,
but it is showing error like
task # 0
from epsilon : error #        
reading namelist ENERGY_GRID

please tell me, why this problem is showing when i run this following code.
&INPUTPP
calculation     = 'eps',
outdir          = './outdir' 
/

&ENERGY_GRID
 smeartype      = 'gauss',
 intersmear     = 0.15,
 intrasmear     = 0.0,
 wmax           = 10.0,
 wmin           = 0.0,
 nw             = 600,
 shift          = 0.0,
 /


Welcome!Please use code block to show your input epsilon.x to better understanding what you did.

Could you be able to solve your problem?
